# Proof verification: $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational for prime $p$

Tags: solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational for prime $p$. I know how to prove the result when $p = 2$, but I'm not fully certain that every element of my proof generalizes to the case where $p$ is a general prime. In particular, I wrote the proof a bit differently. I'd appreciate if someone could provide some feedback on my proof.

> Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\sqrt{p}$ were rational. Then $\sqrt{p} = \frac{m}{n}$ for some $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $q^2 = (-q)^2$ for any $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{p} > 0$, we may assume that $m$ and $n$ are positive. Furthermore, cancelling any common prime factors, we can assume without loss of generality that $m$ and $n$ share no common factors other than $1$. Then $p = \left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^2 = \frac{m^2}{n^2}$, so $pn^2 = m^2$. As $p \mid m^2$, one has $p \mid m$; if $p \nmid m$, then $p \nmid m^2$ by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. So $pk = m$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $pn^2 = (pk)^2 =  p^2 k^2$ and hence $n^2 = pk^2$. Therefore, $p \mid n^2$ and hence $p \mid n$, contradicting the fact that $m$ and $n$ were relatively prime. Therefore, $\sqrt{p}$, which cannot be written as a ratio of integers, is irrational.

How does this look?

Comment: Yes this is good. The presentation can be improved slightly, but it is just more of a nitpick.

Comment: @Vis37 Thank you very much. I would appreciate any feedback you have on the presentation of the proof.

Comment: If you are familiar with minimal polynomials, you can establish a more elegant proof.

Comment: i think a nicer proof is to show that if $m,n$ are coprime (i.e., have no common factors $> 1$), then so are $m^2, n^2$. From this it follows that if $\frac mn$ is not integer, then neither is $\frac{m^2}{n^2}$. Thus if $p = \frac{m^2}{n^2}$ is integer, then so is $q = \frac mn$, so $p$ is the square of some other integer. That is, the square root of any non-negative integer is either another integer, or it is irrational.